# I am using reactJs useState and useContext but the useState value dosen't seem to be updating

Tags: reactjs

The value of the useState dose not change when I call the function that is suppose to update it in one of my components

Below is the Context.js component

```
const Contexts = createContext({
     signIn: () => {},
     signOut: () => {},
     result: false
})

export function UserSlice (props){
     const [userActiveStatus, setUserActiveStatus] = useState(false);
     function signedIn(){
          setUserActiveStatus(true);
     }
     function signedOut(){
          setUserActiveStatus(false);
     }
     const value = {
          result : userActiveStatus,
          signIn: signedIn,
          signOut: signedOut
     }

     return <Contexts.Provider value = {value}>
          {props.children}
     </Contexts.Provider>
}
export default Contexts
```

The value of 'result' always remains 'false' even when I call the 'signIn' function.
I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Thanks.

```
     const emailRef = useRef();
     const passwordRef = useRef();
     const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
     const [errorAlert, setErrorAlert] = useState(false);
     const [alertText, setAlertText] = useState('');
     const currentUser = useAuth();
     const navigate = useNavigate();
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
async function handleLogin(e){
          setLoading(true);
          e.preventDefault();
          if(passwordRef.current.value == ''){
               setErrorAlert(true);
               setAlertText('Input password');
          }else if(emailRef.current.value == ''){
               setErrorAlert(true);
               setAlertText('Input email address');
          }else{
               await login(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value).then((userCredential) => {
                    const user = userCredential.user;
                    console.log(user);
                    navigate('/home');
                    userStatus.signIn();
                    console.log(userStatus.result)
               }).catch(err => {
                    //
               });
          }
         
          setLoading(false);
          clearForm();
     }
```

I called the signIn function in the handleLogin function

```
function App() {
  const currentUser = useAuth();
  const userStatus = useContext(Contexts);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserSlice>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
              {!userStatus.result && <Route path = "/" element = {<LandingPage />} />}
              <Route path = "/home" element={<Home />} /> 
              <Route path = "/sign_in" element={<SignIn />} /> 
            </Routes>
            <Footer/>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </UserSlice>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the component I wrapped the UserSlice around

Comment: Can you show us where you call signedIn?

Comment: Nicholas I have added the code where I called the function. Thanks

Comment: Ok, you're missing the line that accesses the context, so i have to guess it's something like `const userStatus = useContext(Contexts)`?. Also, where is this component relative to `UserSlice`? It needs to be a descendant of UserSlice.

Comment: I am wrapping the userSlice around the whole components so it will be available to all components. I will show you what I mean

Comment: `console.log(userStatus.result)` Is this how you're trying to verify that it worked? Because that line will always log the old value. Only once the component rerenders will you get a new value.

Comment: Not Really, I wanted a component to show only when the value is false and it does not work

Answer (score 0):

For context to work, the provider needs to be *higher* up the component tree than the consumer. You are consuming it at the very top level, in App:

```
const userStatus = useContext(Contexts);
```

Since there is no provider above this, you are getting the default value, which has empty functions and is always false. You will need to rearrange things so the provider is at the top. For example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserSlice>
        <MyRoutes/>
      </UserSlice>
    </div>
  );
}

function MyRoutes() {
  const currentUser = useAuth();
  const userStatus = useContext(Contexts);
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        {!userStatus.result && <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />} />}
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/sign_in" element={<SignIn />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: Wowwwwww. Thank you so much, it worked immediately. Thanks for sharing, I am so grateful